# How to fix a compiling warning on a C program 'char *'

Tags: c, compiler-warnings

I'm getting the below warning on a C program. It does run. However, how do I fix the warning?

```
warning: format specifies type 'char *' but the argument has type 'char (*)[100]' [-Wformat]
            printf("%s\n", &buf);
```

The code looks like this:

```
FILE *fp = fopen(filename, "r");
int len = 0;
char buf[100];

printf("\n sorting \n");
while (fscanf(fp, "%s", buf) != EOF)
{
    printf("%s\n", &buf);
    len++;
}

printf("Sorted\n");
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This line is wrong:

```
    printf("%s\n", &buf);
```

As the warning says, you need to match `%s` with a `char *` parameter. `buf` is an array, so just using its name in this context will cause it to decay into a pointer to its first element - exactly what you want:

```
    printf("%s\n", buf);
```

Using the `&` explicitly passes a pointer to your array; it'll be the same literal address, but has a different type, and that's what your warning is saying.

Comment: I see! Understood. Thank you very much Carl.